# Streamwrite class works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

So here's the code in C# .Net.

```
        string linie = txtFirstName.Text + "," + txtLastName.Text + "," + txtBirthday.Text + "," + txtEmail.Text + ",";

        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"D:/Hosting/2691577/html/gshccadmin/site1/excel_formdata/birthday_club.csv", true);
        write.WriteLine(linie);
        write.Flush();
        write.Close();`
```

Anyone know why this code behind function works in Firefox but not IE.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define "Works". You can be absolutely sure that this piece of code runs exactly the same way in IE and Firefox - it runs on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: You probably need to muck around with your response headers to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Well in Firefox it actually writes to the file and then follows the response.redirect immediately after. In IE no write, no redirect. I press the submit and the function doesn't fire at all.

Comment: **Update** I took out all the streamwriter code and just ran a simple server side Response.Redirect with the button and it doesn't work in IE either. Any one have any idea why a server side button would work in one browser vs another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the content of your csv file look like? IE likes to auto-format XML and other types data to "look nicer" for the user, which sometimes removes the actual intent of the data to be rendered/displayed.

You may need to change the structure/content of the data in the source file, or dump the contents into an HTML literal control in order to get it to render properly.

Comment: Well it's just basic info the titles of the ID's say it all. Name info a birthday and email address.

Comment: If you right click on the page and "view source" do you see any data there, or is it a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

This is server-side code that is not dependent on the browser.

I'm guessing whatever is triggering this code from the client-side has a browser specific bug that is causing the code to not be called (or be called with incorrect parameters).